# Is it proof by contradiction?

Tags: proof-writing

In a proof of the statement "A closed ball $\bar{B}\left(a,r\right)$ is a closed set", author first took complement of  $\bar{B}\left(a,r\right)$ and proved it an open ball.
 I was wondering whether the author used  proof by contradiction here.

Comment: To whoever may know: is the tag *proof theory* appropiate here?

Comment: @GitGud I wouldn't say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the author took the complement of $\bar B(a,r)$ and proved it is an **open set**. This is a direct proof, since we usually define **closed sets** as those whose *complement* is an **open set**. Now, I guess you define open sets as those with the following property: given any point $x$ in the set, call it $O$, there is an open ball $B(x,r)$ about $x$ such that $x\in B(x,r)\subseteq O$.

The definition of open and closed may be slightly confusing at first. In everyday language, open means exactly *not closed* and closed means exactly *not* open. However, the definition in mathematics has a slight difference:

> A set $A$ is open if and only if its **complement** (what *is not* $A$, in contrast to what is $A$) is closed.

In particular (we consider the usual metric $|x-y|=d(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R$)

- There are sets that are closed, but not open: $[a,b]$
- There are sets that are open, but not closed: $(a,b)$
- There are sets that are not closed, nor open: $[a,b)$
- There are sets that are both open and closed: $\Bbb R$

Comment: @AWertheim All open balls are open sets, but not conversely. The complement of a closed ball is most definitively not an open ball, which seems to be what Ansu says: "...and proved it an open ball." Maybe he missed a long sentences such as "and proved *every point in the complement can be surrounded by* an open ball *entirely contained in the set*" =)

Comment: Ah, indeed, I see your point. Nitpicking withdrawn. :)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a proof by contradicition. He merely used the fact that $\overline B(a,r)$ is closed, if and only if,  $X\setminus \overline B(a,r)$ is open. (I suppose here $X=\Bbb R^n$, for some $n\in \Bbb N$).

He could have used proof by contradiction to prove that $X\setminus \overline B(a,r)$ is open or to prove facts leading up to the above theorem, but explicitly he didn't prove that $\overline B(a,r)$ is closed by contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

No, the author did not use *proof by contradiction*.

What is proof by contradiction? If you want to prove that a statement is true, you assume that the statement is false and derive a contradiction.

Note that the negation (the opposite) of being open is not being closed.

In your case, the author simply used that a set is closed if and only if the complement is open.